# Java StringBuilder / String is '<Unreadable>'

Tags: java, string, utf-8, stringbuilder

I have a byte array `bytes` of UTF-8 encoded strings which I want to convert to a String.
bytes.length is about 130000

`String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`
should do the job.
However str gets the value '<Unreadable>'

Converting bytes line by line and printing it out works nicely.
However appending the lines in a StringBuilder fails as well. Again the content of the StringBuilder r will be '<Unreadable>'.
So I thought there might be an unreadable byte in the array.
But `r.substring(60000, r.count)` works well, and `r.substring(1,60000)`, too.
Is there any problem with the size of the byte array?? Maximum size of String/StringBuilder is 2^32 - 1 so there should be no problem.

```
      ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
      InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(bais);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
      // String readBuf = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining()); gives '<Unreadable>'           
      String readed;
      StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
      while ((readed = in. readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(readed); // works fine
          r=r.append(readed);
      }
```

After the loop r.toString() is '<Unreadable>'
Any ideas why I cannot convert the byte array to a String/StringBuilder?

Comment: For debugging and to make your code more of an [mre] try appending an arbitrary byte 130000 times to a `StringBuilder`

Comment: You are aware are you not, that, depending on your system file.encoding, it's not necessarily the case that an arbitrary byte array can be encoded as a valid string? That comment applies to the comment by  @c0der too

Comment: the first half of the StringBuilder is 'readable' and the second half is readable: "r.substring(60000, r.count); r.substring(1,60000)" .
But the entire StringBuilder is not ....

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same. The String was `"<Unreadable>"` if it was made from file bigger then 50000 bytes. But `String.lenght()` showed 50000+ bytes! I found that the text `"<Unreadable">` returned the IDE (Netbeans 11) in debug tools. So, the String was OK, but Netbeans didn't show the right content. It showed `"<Unreadable>"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this behavior, and I have not been able to.  We need a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make any real progress on this.   And full details of the Java version and vendor, and any other tools that may be implicated.

However I do have one definite thing to report.  I have copies of the OpenJDK source code for Java 6, 7, 8, 11 and 17 in a searchable form.  When I search the source code for `Unreadable`, NONE of the hits I get are relevant.  (Indeed, they are all in the respective `test` trees!)  This is very odd.

My tentative conclusion is that this `<Unreadable>` string you are seeing is NOT coming from OpenJDK / Oracle Java.  Either you are using a different vendor's Java, or it is coming from a tool such as your IDE.

---

**UPDATE**

Looking at the [Netbeans code](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/c084119009d2e0f736f225d706bc1827af283501/java/debugger.jpda/src/org/netbeans/modules/debugger/jpda/models/ShortenedStrings.java#L179) that [@BrainStorm.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366594/brainstorm-exe) found, the problem occurs because the debugger is getting unexpected (non-character) data from the debug agent while trying to retrieve the string's characters.

It is difficult to figure out what caused this, but I have a couple of ideas:

- One possibility is that the `String` object is being mutated or deleted in the target JVM.  The former seems unlikely, and I would have thought that the `String` would be reachable ... by virtual of the fact that the debug agent has a reference to it.  (But maybe not.)
- The second possibility is that there is a internal incompatibility between the representation of `String` in the target JVM and Netbean's assumptions about it.

  - Netbeans seems to be assuming that the `value` field of `String` is a `char[]`.  Note that line 178 in the above it is expecting `get(i)` to have returned a `CharValue`; i.e. a JDI wrapper for a primitive `char`.
  - If you look at the evolution of the `String` class over time, the type of the private `String.value` field changed from `char[]` to `byte[]` when they introduced compressed strings in Java 9.

  So if Netbeans is expecting `value` to be a `char[]` when it is actually a `byte[]` any "long" strings will be displayed as `<Unreadable>`.

  That is a Netbeans bug!  And indeed there is an [issue](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/4123) for it.  And indeed someone else has come up with the same theory as I did.

Comment: It appears this is coming from the Netbeans IDE. I do believe the relevant line is https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/c084119009d2e0f736f225d706bc1827af283501/java/debugger.jpda/src/org/netbeans/modules/debugger/jpda/models/ShortenedStrings.java#L179